# Iphone sms app issue

Tags: iphone

iam making an application where i have to send a same body sms to my contact list . I m using

```
Class messageClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController"));
    if (messageClass != nil)
    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
        {
if ([appdelegate.NumberArray count] > 0) {


            NSString *aa = [appdelegate.NumberArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSMutableArray *myArray = [aa componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


            NSString *n = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *m=[myArray objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString *new = [appdelegate.globalmsg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"forgot" withString:n];
            controller.body = new;
            controller.recipients= [NSArray arrayWithObject:m];
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
                //if([appdelegate.NumberArray count] ==2 ){
                  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

im taking out my contact one by one from my mutable array . the problem is that my program sending an sms one at a time, not to the complete list. and if i wanted to send sms to next person i have to click send button again. is there any way i can send sms to everyone without clicking that send button again again?

u can check this app .... http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/automatic-custom-sms/id409247779 in this app last page comes automatically and send everyone from your contact list. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i fix it. i use a local variable an initialize it in view did load with value 0 and then in view did appear update it to 1 and make making present model view appear till my array finished.